# oh-my-zsh : concatenate 2 aliases

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I try to create a git alias in oh-my-zsh to create and push a new branch in one row:

```
alias gnb='git checkout -b $@ && git push -u origin $@'
```

If I type

```
gnb foo
```

I have this error :

```
error: switch `b' requires a value
```

If I split this alias in 2:

```
alias gnb='git checkout -b $@'
alias gpb 'git push -u origin $@'
```

And call them, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a function as follow :

```
function gnb {
  git checkout -b $1 && git push -u origin $1
}
```